# Different levels of physical model solvability and why reality doesn't care

Tags: mathematical-physics, mathematics, special-functions

1. In studying physics, one may get the impression that there exists some underlying or even physical difference between models, which solution - motion of a body, wave function - can be found explicitly, fully, and on a piece of paper, and models where we arrive at some equation and proclaim that the solution to this equation is called that function.

   Take for example the trigonometric functions vs the Bessel functions. On every undergraduate course you spend hours analyzing and solving problems which in the end produce harmonic solutions, whereas the Bessel functions occur somewhat more rarely, in more difficult problems (say, spherical well or circular membrane vibrations) and often are given way less thought and explanation, at least in my experience. Certainly, without taking some course on special functions or mathematical methods of physics, they - and other similar cases, like the full solution to the pendulum equation without the small-angle approximation - may leave the impression of being a bit weird, maybe even a copout for when mathematics is no longer flexible, or even beautiful, enough.

   But is there really any difference from a mathematical standpoint? Sure, the fundamental functions such as exponents or polynomials are exceptional in that regard, that they can be explained in detail much earlier in one's education and arise from basic concepts, the sine being a ratio of some triangle sides etc. But actually, isn't that the weird exception and in reality nothing really separates them from the Bessels and Airys besides this lucky simplicity? And what does it really mean when we can express a solution after pages of calculation "with simple expressions" or something along those lines?
   $$\\$$
2. Mathematics, in many applications, seems to explain our world to amazing precision, which itself is far from obvious and often discussed on philosophical grounds. The fact stands: exceptions from general relativity or quantum mechanics haven't been found experimentally. It really seems that reality follows rules which we're able to identify.

   Why then can we complicate our problems to the point that calculation isn't feasible and we can't find the exact solution? If reality follows the same rules, why is it so "easy" for her to move the planets in the solar system according to GR and produce atoms with many electrons, hyperfine structure and whatnot, while we and our computers have problems simulating even the easiest models using - maybe - the same theories?

It seems as if mathematics was at the same time the perfect tool and an inadequate one. I don't think it's a question of computational power, for we could complicate our models practically indefinitely and reality still would have no problem with applying all rules of physics to them. And of course there's no saying that what we believe to be correct in some limit, like GR, is actually right, but at least what's probable is that the better theory wouldn't be any simpler in use and the problem would stand.

Comment: Related to your first question: [Why are special functions special?](https://michaelberryphysics.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/berry326.pdf), MV Berry, [*Physics Today* **54**, 11 (2001)](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1372098).

Comment: "Is there something fascinating here?" Is a question that cannot be objectively answered. No one can say if you are right or wrong. Although something I did think of while reading this as a sort of "objection" is that nature does not do calculations in order to follow the laws of physics.

Comment: True, removed it.

Comment: Even then, this is still too opinion based for this site. A great discussion to have, for sure, but not here.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't follow calculations, but why then some of its movements seem to be directly connected to results of calculations.

Comment: Do you know of any proper place to have such a discussion?

Comment: This topic would be fine in [The h Bar](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar), when there are enough people around.

Comment: Have you read Wigner's classic article, [The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Mathematics in the Natural Sciences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unreasonable_Effectiveness_of_Mathematics_in_the_Natural_Sciences)?

Comment: Actually I have, and this question was partially inspired by it. I intend to return to the article in the future in order to look for more insight, but what interests me here is not exactly the "unreasonable effectiveness", rather the difficulty of applying this unreasonably effective language to harder problems.

Answer (score 1):

> If reality follows the same rules, why is it so "easy" for her to move the planets in the solar system according to GR and produce atoms with many electrons, hyperfine structure and whatnot, while we and our computers have problems simulating even the easiest models using - maybe - the same theories?

Computers themselves are physical systems; and all physical systems do a kind of computing, in that they automatically go from one state to another.

Physically, each of our computers is a tiny tiny piece of the universe. Also, they use physical resources inefficiently, at least when compared to nature, where one atom is enough to 'compute' the dynamics of that atom, by being the thing itself. Whereas in a computer, we may use large numbers of atoms to simulate that single atom. It is because human beings want to be able to instruct the computer what to do, and they want to be able to read out the results.

In the case of planets orbiting the sun, it would be simply impossible for a little object less than a meter in size to simulate so many giga-avogadros of atoms, were it not that in this case, they engage in a dynamics which can be approximated by massive simplifications. We do not simulate the orbits of the planets, by simulating avogadros of atoms engaged in electromagnetic and gravitational interactions. We skip the electromagnetism entirely, as well as the individual atoms, and just talk about gravitational interactions among point masses or mass distributions.

You could therefore turn this question around and say, why is it possible at all for us to calculate anything about how nature works in the large? There will be direct answers to that question, which amount to spelling out in mathematical detail, the nature of approximations like the one I just mentioned, and the computational complexity of engaging in them. But there could be a deeper reason why simplicity of approximation repeatedly emerges at different scales.

Comment: I see, from that perspective it really does look like a question of computational power, especially the part with people needing to input and output information, and the inefficient use of atoms. However, can you think of an example when even making the broadest approximations while still calculating something useful is still too hard for us to compute? A situation where the complexity of involved mathematics is itself the hurdle, and not for example the number of objects which need to be analyzed.

Comment: The most inherently difficult calculations might be path integrals for strongly coupled QFTs, as in QCD. But these can still be performed by brute force, as in lattice QCD.